# Got Nan while mapping the values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({"2": "man", "1": "woman"})
```

Got `NaN` instead of man&woman

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the type of gender is int, so this would fix your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df["gender"]=[1,2,1,2,2,1]
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({2: "man", 1: "woman"})
print(df)
```

The output:

```
  gender
0  woman
1    man
2  woman
3    man
4    man
5  woman
```

Comment: Idk even with pd isnt working...(

Comment: @DaniilZakharov Try *just* `df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({2: "man", 1: "woman"})` in your code. Everything else is set up as part of Kalyan's answer. If you're already overwritten `df['gender']` with `NaNs`, you'll have to go back a couple of steps in your code to restore them.

Comment: @DaniilZakharov If you are using any note book do check the values of 'gender' column. It could be Nan as  suggested. Just re-run the entire code.

Comment: Lol the problem was that int was in " " )) Thy guys

Comment: @DaniilZakharov If the problem is solved do mark the answer as correct so that the question would be marked as answered. Thank you. :)